# Why does text on my monitor look so horrible?

Tags: windows-10, display

I just got a new monitor a couple days ago and text looks horrible on it. It's the Acer XFA240. I'm using the standard display port cable that was provided with the monitor.

I've tried to mess with the monitor settings and even installed a profile for it (which helped with the washed out look) but texts looks so bad. I can even see red and blue outlines around the text (like in extra pixels I guess?). I'm not a very computer savvy person but the look of it makes me not even want to use it.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me out. Here's some information that might be helpful: Running 1920x1080 144hz over display port.

Edit:I have now tried the following as per suggested by some comments. 
I ran the monitor test and nothing seemed out of order besides the gradient test. The text in the monitor test looks significantly better than text everywhere else. I have tried re-calibrating clear type. It didn't help. I have tried just a 60hz refresh rate, it didn't change anything. And, I have just verified via OSD that my monitor is running at 1920x1080@145hz.

Here's an Image of some text.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some picture of it? Which exact model of monitor? What type of cable do you use? Have you tried with different cable? Is that an existing pc which worked well with previous monitor?...

Comment: @MátéJuhász I'll post some pictures tomorrow. It's the Acer XFA240. I'm using the standard display port cable that was provided with the monitor. The old monitor I used on this pc didn't exactly work well but, it didn't have this text issue.

Comment: *"Looks horrible"* is a subjective evaluation.  Try using monitor tests such as  https://www.eizo.be/monitor-test/ or http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/, and try objective descriptions.  Also check your your monitor for various adjustments, especially for `phase`.

Comment: What video adapter are you using?  Have you tried just a 60 Hz refresh rate?

Comment: Please tag your question with the operating system you're using. If you're using Windows, did you try recalibrating cleartype?

Comment: Are you sure you are running 1920x1080 144Hz? You'd better verify this on the monitor's OSD. Most horrible text syndrome is due to not using the native resolution and the picture scaler in the monitor is doing a bad job - like doing image sharpen. I saw https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/acer-xfa240-144hz-gaming-monitor,6320.html there is an OSD menu picture which includes "super sharpeness"... This monitor is advanced which contain some image processing tech which sometimes result in horrible text.

Comment: Turn everything down in the monitor OSD menu and let the monitor display the original image from PC and make sure it is 1920*1080. Better to use 60Hz first.

Comment: @MMM: Incidentally, the ClearType calibrator in Win10 accidentally sets the gamma for DirectWrite to the same very high value no matter what I've actually tried to pick, so e.g. Start Menu looks horrible after calibro until I fix the setting by hand...

Comment: probably cleartype has been changed from RGB to BGR somehow, which makes the red and blue components swapped and appear more clearly. Just press Windows key, type cleartype and run "Adjust cleartype text"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does text look so Horrible on my HD monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/146841/why-does-text-look-so-horrible-on-my-hd-monitor)

Comment: Okay, let me answer a few things here. I ran the monitor test and nothing seemed out of order besides the gradient test. The text in the monitor test looks significantly better than text everywhere else. I have tried recalibrating clear type. It didn't help. I have tried just a 60hz refresh rate, it didn't change anything. And, I have just verified via OSD that my monitor is running at 1920x1080@145hz. At this point I am just considering returning the monitor.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LzkLNFf.png
As you can see theres the red and blue outline along with some little like extra pixels or something on some of the letters. I could edit the post with an image because I don't have enough rep

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to make your question better by adding all of this requested information. There should not be a full conversation happening in the comments down here.

Comment: You can still place the image link in the question. Someone with enough rep can then edit the question to in-line the image.

Comment: Are you using a graphics card? Please mention the specs required. Also try changing the resolution and refresh rate to 75Hz or 60Hz

Comment: Yes, I'm using a NVIDIA 1060 3GB. I've tried 60Hz, and 75hz. No difference @SrinivasV